# Woocommerce - How to Show product tags in shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to display my product tags under the price area for every products in shop page . and when someone clicks on the tags, products be Filtered by the tag

Comment: Great.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [WooCommerce Display Products by Tags](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-display-products-by-tags/) plugin? You can use it to display product tags. You just have to use a simple shortcode, like `product_tag tags="shirts,pants"`, to do it.